# DateTime.ParseExact creates a proper Date Object but the Date is set wrong

Tags: c#, date, datetime

So i have this Date String "2014-12-10T19:26:37.381467" which i get from a PostgreSQL Database.

I have a function lets say

```
public static bool String2DatePG(string s, out DateTime dd)
{
    try
    {
        CultureInfo USCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us", false);
        var formatstring = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            var msc = s.Split('.');
            var mscc = msc.Count();
            if (mscc <= 0)
            {
                dd = DateTime.ParseExact(s, formatstring , USCulture);
                return true;
            }

            var fc = msc.Last();
            var fcc = fc.Count();                   

            if (fcc > 0)
            {
                var newformat = formatstring + '.';

                for (int i = 0; i < fcc; i++)
                {
                    newformat += 'f';
                }

                dd = DateTime.ParseExact(s, newformat, USCulture);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    dd = DateTime.MinValue;
    return false;
}
```

It reads through the datestring, checks how many millisecond digits there are and creates a format string depending on that.
The string i get from the DB looks good i think but when dd object is set to something weird like shown in the picutre below:

[image: Inspection of DateTime object dd]

I have no clue what's going wrong here, but when i try to save the value again the DB it seems to set the Date to Dates quite different than the one i mentioned in my first sentence, like seen in the Picture in the Date Object with the + sign in the front. All the other objects of the DateTime seem to be fine, or am i totally missing something here?

Comment: Sorry - what's weird about the date represented in your picture? It seems to closely match the date you posted as the top of your question

Comment: It's set to 12:00:00 AM although the date from the string in my first sentence says "19:26:37" ...

Comment: That first part of the date is only the date part - you can see "TimeOfDay" as another property lower in your object window

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Seems my problem lies somewhere else...

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your DateTime object.  The time is ignored in this property and therefore defaults to 12 a.m.

From MSDN:

> Because the DateTime type represents both dates and times in a single type, it is important to avoid misinterpreting a date returned by the Date property as a date and time.

If your are testing by sending `dd.Date` back to the database, try just saving `dd` instead.